# How to change duration of animated UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I want to change my animated `UIImage` in `UIImageView` `duration` during runtime, but it's property is read-only and there are no methods like `setDuration`. Is it possible?
In `viewDidLoad` i call this

```
-(void)prepareImage
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"image-" duration:1.0f];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:squirrelImage];
    self.imageView=imageView; //property with UIImageView
}
```

Then on some event i do this

```
-(UIImageView *)redrawedImage
{
    UIImageView *newImageView = self.imageView;

    //a lot of translations and scales

    return newImageView;
}
```

and i want to put animation's duration change inside without resetting the whole animation.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myname.png"];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                  duration:5.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                  self.imageView.image = toImage;
                } completion:nil];
```

use this code may help your....

Comment: maybe my question wasn't complete - i've made `UIImage` as `[UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"prefix-" duration:1.5f]` so it's duration is hardcoded and `duration` is read-only property.